# How to wait until the frame is done?

Tags: c#, godot-4

According to Google, `await ToSignal(GetTree(), "idle_frame");` should wait until the next frame. However, in Godot 4.0's current master branch (**mono build!**), this fails with:

```
Ready(): In Object of type 'SceneTree': Attempt to connect nonexistent signal 'idle_frame' to callable 'Node3D(SomeScript.cs)::SignalAwaiterMiddleman::idle_frame'.
```

It seems like the API changed in Godot 4.0. Do you have any ideas how to wait until either the next frame or until the current frame has finished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Disclaimer: Mono Build? I haven't tried at the time of writing.*

This is the GDScript 2.0 you would be trying to mimic in C#:

```
await get_tree().process_frame
```

Thus, I believe in C# it should say:

```
await ToSignal(GetTree(), SceneTree.SignalName.ProcessFrame);
```

Comment: Just playing around with Godot 4.0's Mono Build - it is running pretty stable compared to two/three months ago.

Comment: Slight tweak to this: `await ToSignal(GetTree(), SceneTree.SignalName.ProcessFrame);` does the same thing without a string literal. Not a big deal, but feels a little closer to what you get with GDScript.